# Is there such thing as an Availability Group failover trigger?

Tags: sql-server

Is there such thing as a trigger for Availability Group failovers?

I want a certain action to happen when an AG fails over. Specifically, I want to turn on a database setting (turning on RCSI). I want to do this on a failover in order to minimize disruption to 24/7 workloads and scheduled maintenance windows are hard to come by.

I know that `sp_procoption` can be used to mark procedures as startup procedures. 
This seems like it could work for failover clusters, but not for Availability Groups.

I did consider adding an alert (`sp_add_alert`) on message_id=26069 in order to respond to failover actions with a sql agent job. But this seems less direct and in practice it seems slow

Comment: Is this a common thing others would want? Or is it just me?

Comment: Hmm, what’s the advantage of not having RCSI enabled on the secondary by default? Is it because of the additional versioning information? (If so I Wonder if this is actually a bad thing to not have slots for versioning in your existing rows)?

Comment: You can’t have different RCSI settings on primary and secondary. Any queries that read on the secondary node run under Snapshot isolation any way.

Comment: If you cannot have different settings I don’t understand what the trigger should do?

Comment: I wanted to change the setting during a failover. The timing was the important part. The change in the RCSI setting takes a small outage, so does the failover. I wanted one to happen at the same time as the other.

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense. Not sure if that would work however.

Comment: I guess you could reconfigure the EventLog polling interval for Agent (registry entry). Default is 20 seconds. But that has a limit, of course, And it feels a bit ... dirty. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Triggers are not at an instance or AG level. You'd need to base something on the failover event or better yet, as part of a SQL Server Agent job, just check to see if that replica is the primary and then do (or not do) something.

Answer (score 4):

I've done things like this before, but all I found available was the alerts. There's actually 2 different alerts, one that fires for each database in the AG, and another that fires when the entire AG fails over. So you have some flexibility.